# How to load a Groovy File and call a method in it via Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkinsfile as below in Declarative Pipeline format.

```
pipeline{
    agent{
        label 'xyz-test'
    }
    options{
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
        timestamps()
    }
    environment {
        UTILITY = load pwd() + 'path to /utils.groovy'
    }
    stages{
        stage('Build'){
            steps{
                sh "${UTILITY.functionX()}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a groovy file with name **utils.groovy**

```
def functionX(){
}

def functionY(){
}

return this;
```

When I call functionX() in such a way, I am getting below error in the console.

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method
```

Comment: Where is `utils.groovy` located in the your library hierarchy?

Comment: Its located in <Project Name>/lib/pipeline_scripts/utils.groovy. Whereas my pipeline script located in <Project Name>/lib/pipeline_scripts/utilities/Jenkinsfile.groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use 'load' steps from 'Pipeline: Groovy' plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-cps) in a script block.
(https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#-load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script)

ex:

```
stages {
    stage ("load scripts"){
        steps {
            script {
                scripts=load "jenkins/scripts/loadScripts.groovy"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Executing statements inside script block do require script approval from Jenkins Admin which is prohibited by our Tech Arch. Is there any other way we can achieve without script block as we do in scripted pipeline.

Comment: I'm not so sure it requires to be inside a script block actually, since load is referenced as a step for the plugin 'Pipeline, groovy'. I'll do some testing tomorrow,  I'll let you now.

Comment: Your solution is working fine now. Probably because of this plugin https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/

Comment: how do you get those files in that location in the first place?